# Cómo puedo sacar los 5 números mayores de un vector en JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy practicando JAVA y debo resolver el siguiente ejercicio:
En un vector de 23 posiciones se tienen las temperaturas máximas de las capitales de las 23 provincias argentinas en el último mes. A partir de esta información, un noticiero desea determinar el top 5 de las temperaturas más altas para poder mostrar en la pantalla de su programa, para ello se necesita un programa que sea capaz de recorrer el vector de temperaturas, determinar las 5 más altas y copiarlas en un nuevo vector de 5 posiciones.

He llegado hasta este punto, pero en las 5 posiciones me inscribe la misma temperatura (la más alta) en lugar de las 5 más altas. ¿Como podría hacer para inscribir las 5 temperaturas más altas?

```
     double [] temperaturas ={22,32,40,35,23,20,15,34,12,25,17,35, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33};  
      double [] maxNum = new double [5];
      double mayor=0;
      double x=0;
      
      for (int i=0;i<maxNum.length;i++ ){
          for (int j=0;j<temperaturas.length;j++) {    
         if(temperaturas[j]>mayor){
            mayor=temperaturas[j];
            x=j;} }maxNum[i]=mayor;   
System.out.println("Temperatura máxima "+ i + " es igual a: " + maxNum [i]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas guardando el indice del mayor numero en la variable `x` esta debe ser del mismo tipo del indice (int)

```
int x=0;
          
          for (int i=0;i<maxNum.length;i++ ){
              for (int j=0;j<temperaturas.length;j++) {    
                    if(temperaturas[j]>mayor){
                      mayor=temperaturas[j]; 
                      x=j;                
                    } 
          }
    //si ya obtuviste el mayor numero ,debes reemplazar ese valor mayor para que no lo vuelva a tomar en  cuenta en una próxima iteracion 
          temperaturas[x]=0;  
          maxNum[i]=mayor;
//asimismo reemplzar el valor de maxNum después de ser guardado en el numero array
          mayor=0;   
    System.out.println("Temperatura máxima "+ i + " es igual a: " + maxNum [i]);}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacerlo de 2 formas: de forma algorítmica usando bucles básicos como for y while, o usando métodos estáticos de las clases Arrays y Collections, acá tenes las soluciones con sus aclaraciones pero ambas funcionan bien:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main { 
 
  public static void main (String[] args){
   
    Integer [] temperaturas = {22,32,40,23,20,15,34,12,25,100,35, 23, 24, 51, 26, 27, 28, 87, 30, 31, 32, 33};  
    int [] maxNums = {0,0,0,0,0}; // array de resultados metodo 1
    Integer [] maxNums2 = {0,0,0,0,0}; // array de resultados metodo 2
    
    // metodo 1:

    int x=0; // iterador del while

    while(x < maxNums.length){ // iteramos las posiciones del array resultado
      for(int i=0;i<temperaturas.length;i++){ // iteramos las temperaturas
        if(temperaturas[i]>maxNums[x]) // si la temperatura actual es mayor a maxNums en el indice x:
          if(x > 0 && temperaturas[i]<maxNums[x - 1]) maxNums[x] = temperaturas[i]; 
          // arriba se verifica que esta temperatura sea menor a la temperatura del indice anterior de maxNums
        if(x == 0) // <-- esto solo lo hacemos en la primera iteracion del while, de lo contrario [x - 1] nos lanzara error
          if(temperaturas[i]>=maxNums[0])  maxNums[0] = temperaturas[i]; 
      }
      x++; // incrementamos el indice del while
    }

    for(int i=0;i<maxNums.length;i++) // imprimimos y verificamos
      System.out.println(maxNums[i]);
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    // metodo 2:
    // Para que esto funcione el tipo de temperaturas y de maxNums2 debe ser Integer. Si queres solo variables primitivas como int usa el metodo 1.

    maxNums2 = temperaturas; // ahora el array maxNums2 es igual a temperaturas
    Arrays.sort(maxNums2, Collections.reverseOrder()); // ordenamos ese array inversamente (de mayor a menor)
    Arrays.copyOfRange((maxNums2),0,4); // ahora maxNums2 tiene 5 elementos.

    for(int i=0;i<maxNums.length;i++) // imprimimos y verificamos
      System.out.println(maxNums2[i]);
    
  } 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder!